# Arbitrarily small order

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer and $p$ some prime number not dividing $n$. Let $d$ be the order of $$p\bmod n\in(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times.$$Notice that $d$ divides $\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ denotes Euler's totient function. Consider now the integer
$$m:=m(n,p):=\frac{\phi(n)}{d}.$$

There is no particular reason to assume that the values of $m$ are bounded. In other words, for every $M>0$, one should find corresponding $n$ and $p$ for which $m(n,p)>M$.

I am wondering if there is a straightforward way of seeing this.

---

I was experimenting with this using Python, and was able to observe the following: If we choose $n=3^e$ and $p$ the biggest prime less than or equal to $2\cdot 3^{e-1}+1$, then it appears that $m$ tends towards infinity as $e$ does. I am not sure if this is a good starting point to solve the above question, essentially because $p$ is (of course) not defined in terms of an actual formula.

Another way of solving the question would be to find an infinite family of $n$ for which we can find primes $p_n$ not dividing $n$ such that the order of $p_n\bmod n$ is bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $q$ be a prime and $n=q^e$. Then $n$ has a primitive root $g$.

Let $p$ be a prime congruent to $g^r$ mod $n$, where $r=\phi(n)/2$.
(Thanks to Dirichlet.)

Then $p$ mod $n$ has order $d=2$ and so $\frac{\phi(n)}{d} = \frac{q^{e-1}(q-1)}{2}$, which is clearly unbounded.